# Show that two lines are perpendicular in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I want to show that

> $\overline{AB}\perp\overline{CD}$ if and only if ${\bf Re}\dfrac{a-b}{c-d}=0$, where $a, b, c, d$ are the complex numbers corresponding to the points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$.

I am yet to find a proof for this. Could someone give me some hints?

Comment: Hint: $\arg\big((a-b)/(c-d)\big)$ is the angle between $AB$ and $CD$.

Comment: After working out, a very long way is to assign complex numbers $a$=$a_1+a_2i$ etc for$A,B,C$ and $D$ and work out $Re\frac{a-b}{c-d}$ and multiply with its conjugate. Compare that expression to the expression by setting up slopes (rise over run) and using the fact that the product of two perpendicular lines is $-1$. It isn't the prettiest way to show, there has to be a quicker and more elegant way, perhaps the suggestion of dxiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know the angle of vector $a-b$ with $x$-axis is $\arg(a-b)$ and also the angle of vector $c-d$ with $x$-axis is $\arg(c-d)$, then they are perpendicular if 
$$\arg(a-b)-\arg(c-d)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
or
$$\arg\dfrac{a-b}{c-d}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
this shows that the number $\dfrac{a-b}{c-d}$ is purely imaginary, therfore ${\bf Re}\dfrac{a-b}{c-d}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The lines have direction vectors
$$
AB = b-a \quad CD = d-c
$$
We have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Re}{Re}
\Re \frac{b-a}{d-c} 
= \Re \frac{r_1 e^{i \phi_1}}{r_2 e^{i \phi_2}}
= \Re \frac{r_1}{r_2} e^{i(\phi_1 - \phi_2)}
= \frac{r_1}{r_2} \cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2)
$$
where we switched to polar coordinates.